# ul border length half of li element

Tags: html, css

I want this blue `ul` borders to be like in the center under this black `li` elements and have 50% of the child width, but I don't know how can I achieve this. I've tried with `:before` but seems like it's for only one "ul" element.

```css
#one{
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.a{
    border-bottom: 4px solid blue;
    
}

.b
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
    <ul class="a">
        <li class="b"></li>
        <li class="b"></li>
    </ul>   
    <ul class="a">
        <li class="b"></li>
        <li class="b"></li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can remove your border style, and use this in its place:

```
li {
  position: relative;
}

li:last-of-type:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  bottom: -12px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid blue;
}
```

**Snippet:**

```css
#one{
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.b
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 20px;
}

li {
  position: relative;
}

li:last-of-type:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  bottom: -12px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
    <ul class="a">
        <li class="b"></li>
        <li class="b"></li>
    </ul>   
    <ul class="a">
        <li class="b"></li>
        <li class="b"></li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```